# Sonarqube stopped after Apex plugin installation

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm setting up sonarqube local server and freshly installed latest sonarqube 7.6
started server and successfully launched.

stoped server

installed sonar apex plugin in \extensions\plugins\ folder

started server again

error regarding apex plugin

2019.02.18 17:13:11 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2019.02.18 17:13:11 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2019.02.18 17:13:12 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.02.18 17:13:12 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin]
2019.02.18 17:13:12 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
2019.02.18 17:13:12 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.02.18 17:13:14 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2019.02.18 17:13:14 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 7.6.0.21501 / d56689a5eb122c06cf87375828085609f5a68323
2019.02.18 17:13:14 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar
2019.02.18 17:13:14 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: C:\Users\PawPatel\Documents\sonarqube-7.6\data
2019.02.18 17:13:14 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar
2019.02.18 17:13:14 WARN  web[][o.s.db.dialect.H2] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only.
2019.02.18 17:13:15 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: C:\Users\PawPatel\Documents\sonarqube-7.6
2019.02.18 17:13:15 INFO  web[][o.s.s.u.SystemPasscodeImpl] System authentication by passcode is disabled
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.7.0.1491 / 1d54e49a5f952dfb4ccded090f8043a2a62d0372
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 1.0.1.143 / 65c55e41e32c114704fd597ccea91fc55becb4ec
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin LDAP / 2.2.0.608 / 79dc3fa4393a29667673c70182f3016288b548b7
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarApex / 1.4.0.155 / f71ae433edd0c1f1dbab3fed4d755ef17aef8573
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarC# / 7.10.0.7896 / 4e51d150065288432fd1411d29d5aebf2ab7f133
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarCSS / 1.0.3.724 / 3ad5232345519caed38a24c70fb77e91757833bf
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarFlex / 2.4.0.1222 / 68d9cb3b7daccbc4869c4f2b89d09218d26a0829
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarGo / 1.1.0.1612 / 1809c7be6d88396c0a1b8d597b1e9e0ed8d29730
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarHTML / 3.1.0.1615 / 4181edb5eff5605bec82dc0aa15ecd70eaa5857f
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJS / 5.0.0.6962 / ac2fe7567f3dfeb3295e2e710afd8c06b7760e9d
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJava / 5.10.1.16922 / 448c4b8fce8d8ac53a9a7a7265d4de1c1ac87a4e
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarKotlin / 1.4.0.155 / f71ae433edd0c1f1dbab3fed4d755ef17aef8573
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarPHP / 2.16.0.4355 / 80c76cb14e9eae6bd982fa6ac8c39b2de1f89b6f
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarPython / 1.11.0.2473 / 3ec86bb66699ff9ccf2c00c84f360210eb3ffd8d
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarRuby / 1.4.0.155 / f71ae433edd0c1f1dbab3fed4d755ef17aef8573
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarScala / 1.4.0.155 / f71ae433edd0c1f1dbab3fed4d755ef17aef8573
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarTS / 1.9.0.3766 / 4a4080b78001a78d758d1d0fa0190fb9496b6f57
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarVB / 7.10.0.7896 / 4e51d150065288432fd1411d29d5aebf2ab7f133
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarXML / 2.0.1.2020 / c5b84004face582d56f110e24c29bf9c6a679e69
2019.02.18 17:13:17 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Svn / 1.9.0.1295 / 942e075773975354e32691a60bfd968065703e04
2019.02.18 17:13:19 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter@7afda664 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/system/migrate_db.*, ...], exclusions=[/api/properties*, ...]}]
2019.02.18 17:13:19 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2019.02.18 17:13:20 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to load plugin SonarApex [sonarapex]
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:82)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel4.start(PlatformLevel4.java:573)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:211)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:185)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.access$500(Platform.java:46)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.lambda$doRun$0(Platform.java:119)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(Platform.java:371)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.doRun(Platform.java:119)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.run(Platform.java:355)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sonarsource/plugins/license/api/LicensedPluginRegistration
    at com.A.A.C.F.define(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:72)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sonarsource.plugins.license.api.LicensedPluginRegistration
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
2019.02.18 17:13:21 INFO  web[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process

My sonarqube is latest 7.6 version. copied sonar apex in correct folder. then why my sonarqube is not starting? why this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SonarApex](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarapex.html) plugin is a commercial product.
You cannot install it on SonarQube 7.6 `Community Edition` or `Developer Edition`, you need at least `Enterprise Edition`. Read more at [Plans & Pricing](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/), and do not hesitate to request a trial license. Furthermore, SonarApex is available on [sonarcloud.io](https://sonarcloud.io/) and it's free of charge for public projects or start at 10€/month.